# table name t 10 20 30 40 want output as 10 30 50 70 in sql

Tags: sql

t 10 20 30 40

output 10 30 50 70

Answer (score 1):

One method of doing this is a cumulative sum with a window function:

```
select col,
       sum(col) over (order by col
                      rows between 1 preceding and current row
                     )
from t;
```